# Connecting XML nested SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have tables : A, B, and V in Sql Server.  I'm trying to to print out XML pattern only where B.id = V.id.  However, I'm getting the error message of

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 183 The multi-part identifier "B.id"
>   could not be bound.

How should the XML query be rewritten so that only the XML data joined by id between table B and V print out in the same section.

My original query:

```
select 
A.*,
(
select * from Event
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('event'),TYPE

) B ,
V.*
From A, V
Where B.id = V.id
FOR XML PATH ('main'),TYPE
```

Thank you,
Julie

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired XML output to the question.

Comment: The error message *"The multi-part identifier "B.id" could not be bound."* is easy to explain: You are using the alias `B` with the sub-select `from event`, which is returned as a typed XML. This is not a table, where you'd find a column `id`. Please try to create a [mcve], add minimal sample data to reproduce your issue and add the expected output. This sure is easy, but this is to vague...